# How to access ModelMap attributes on jsp page or on js secretely

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc, security

The use case is - user will request some data, user can edit that data and user can persist data on server side. In this scenario I want to have some integrity of data. Here legitimate use can resend the request from Developer tool by putting some malicious values(user is editing in rich text editor) in the JSON data.

To resolve this I am using an approach of calculating MD5/SHA256 of JSON data and send that hash along with data and at server side recalculate the hash from data and compare that hash with input hash. To make it tough I am using salt while generating the hash. The approach I am using is when user logs in- create a Salt and store that in user's session. When user requests the page i am sending the Salt in ModalMap. When user sends request to persist that JSON data, I will use the salt+data to generate hash

Now, my problem here is I want the salt to be hidden from user. The EL evaluated attributes are visible to user from page source and same is the case for scriptlet or jstl.

So, is there any way of accessing some attribute secretly on JSP page?.

I understand that when JSP gets parsed all those tags gets evaluated.

Minification of JS will make it little harder to find but is will not be impossible to retrieve the salt value.

I also understand that I should have such logic at server side but the requirement is preventing me to do that.

If I cannot access attributes secretly then is there any other approach of doing that?.

I have not included any source code here because it's generic.